# Extension to take control over chrome video player?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When you drag a movie to Google Chrome Browser, it starts playing in the browser. How can I remotely take control over the Play/Pause buttons of this player? (Say by a smartphone)

This is how it looks like:

[image: chrome video player]

Is there an extension for this? Can I create such an extension? If so then what are the main steps?

I tried to `Inspect element` the buttons to see what I *really* need to control but it didn't give me more than the video source url (which is in my computer...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to execute method attached to the DOM element:

```
videoElement= document.querySelector("video");
videoElement.play();
```

Some resources:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video
- https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

It is equivalent to control the video from an extension, place your code in a content script to be able to access to the `video` element, and eventually listen for outside events which you will then trigger back to the player with the above lines.

**A simple example**

```js
document.querySelector("video").play(); //play on page load 

document.querySelector("#play").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector("video").play(); 
});

document.querySelector("#pause").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector("video").pause(); 
});
```

```html
<video src="http://html5demo.braincracking.org/demo/media/windowsill.ogv"   controls loop>
  Video not supported
</video>

<br/>
<button id="play">Play</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make an android app to remotely do this? i.e the app will run on a phone and control the video player that's running on the computer

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know,  element uses shadow DOM features to hide its structure.

Take a look at this tutorial on [Tuts+](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/intro-to-shadow-dom--net-34966) and [HTML 5 Video Tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-video-element) spec on W3C.

**Update**

Take a look at [igrigorik/videospeed](https://github.com/igrigorik/videospeed), it maybe helpful